# SSRS time format issue while exporting to excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I am getting the issue for the column which contains 00:00 format and after exporting excel shows ################## and error -

> "Date and times that are negative or too large show as ######"

SSRS -2016

Below is how I get in Excel

[image]

Comment: quick question, your column for Time did you formatted it in SSRS I mean TextBox property of that field to proper Date

Comment: Yes i converted it using cDate and then again formatted with 00:00 time format